# How to convert date to different formats?

Tags: date, go, time, date-conversion

I would like to convert date format from `2010-01-23 11:44:20` to `Jan 23 '10 at 11:44` in Go. I tried few functions from [time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) package but couldn't make it.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the time package's [`Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) and [`Format`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) to convert it to the desired text format. Both take a reference time (2006-01-02 15:04:05) in the format you require as a parameter which makes the format fairly easy to understand.

```
dtstr1 := "2010-01-23 11:44:20"
dt,_ := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", dtstr1)

dtstr2 := dt.Format("Jan 2 '06 at 15:04")
```

[A playground to test with](https://play.golang.org/p/KlbCQCmaKA).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the time package's Parse and Format functions,
or another way is to write your own formatter function like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

//2010-01-23 11:44:20 to Jan 23 '10 at 11:44
func FormatDateTime(t time.Time) string {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    buffer.WriteString(t.Month().String()[:3])
    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf(" %2d '%2d at %2d:%2d", t.Day(), t.Year()%100, t.Hour(), t.Minute()))
    return buffer.String()
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    str := FormatDateTime(t)
    fmt.Println(str) //Apr 23 '16 at 11:50
}
```