# Golang time.Parse Defining New Format Type

Tags: date, parsing, go, time

I am trying to parse a date of the format "2017/02/28 17:07:54". I am using the time.Parse method.

playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/B_hnws1AGv

This is failing. It produces a time object: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC (which clearly is not the date I am trying to parse).

How can I parse a date of this format? My end goal is to convert  "2017/02/28 17:07:54" to "Feb 28" Note that I do not want "February 28" I want "Feb 28."

I have looked at the following links:

- [How to convert date format in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807596/how-to-convert-date-format-in-golang)
- [Parsing date string in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845172/parsing-date-string-in-golang)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string is using the wrong [reference date](https://godoc.org/time#Parse) (`2006-01-02 15:04:05`). It should be the following:

```
const longForm2 = "2006/01/02 15:04:05"
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize the reference date had to be a specific date.