# How to convert between unusual time formats golang

Tags: vba, go, datetime-format

I referenced this post: [How to convert date format in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807596/how-to-convert-date-format-in-golang) and have this code on the playground:

https://play.golang.org/p/oNFVlDz9JoF

But I can't seem to get it to work. I've padded the month with a 0 and still no dice. The time I'm trying to convert is **4/20/2018 9:08:34 AM** and I want it in this format: **2009-04-20T21:18:44Z**

```
NewLastDate = CDate(LastModified) 'generates 4/20/2018 9:08:34 AM
```

That's from a VBA script. 'LastModified' is in this format: **dddd.ttttt VB/VBA format**

Comment: For one, you're throwing away the errors (`_`) which should be checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go time formats are interesting, you always have to put your formats in terms of (per the docs) https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse

```
01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700
```

I changed your formats a bit so you could see what is happening. I also would advise checking error returns. It also seems like `time.RFC3339` is a good shorthand for what you are looking for on the output side but I may be wrong.

https://play.golang.org/p/eYYdV_UE_Pa

Comment: That was just what I needed. Thanks for the help. The time.RFC3339 was exactly right.